# Handle denied email permission in Facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build Login with Facebook API manually. I am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/ & using following code in my ASP.NET MVC.

Basic idea is to ask users permission, access the users email, auto-register to my system.

Problem is when user un-check access to email & click on Ok on the facebook authentication popup. Next time when user clicks on "Login with Facebook" button, facebook authentication pop-up won't appear, as user has already allowed the access, and I don't get users email. The only way, facebook authentication box re-appear, is user revoke access to my app from his personal facebook account.

Is there another way, I can get the facebook authentication popup again? Or better way to do this?

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
{
    client_id = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
    client_secret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"],
    redirect_uri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookRedirectURL"],
    code = code
});

var accessToken = result.access_token;

// Store the access token in the session
Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

// update the facebook client with the access token so
// we can make requests on behalf of the user
fb.AccessToken = accessToken;

// Get the user's information
dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=first_name,last_name,id,email");
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(me.email))
{
    string email = me.email;
    // Register Or login user
}
else
{
    // Handle declined email permissions
}
```

Comment: If the user declines a permission, you need to re-ask using `auth_type=rerequest`, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#handling // (How to do that with your SDK, you’ll have to check.)

Comment: actually user accepts the permission, just deselects the email from the popup. 'rerequest' doesn't work.

Comment: Hm. Guess you could try and revoke the permission, and then ask again (not sure if you will have to re-ask then) - and see if that gives the user the choice to select an e-mail address to share again ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#revoking